# Is there a comparison of the cost structure of residential electricity in the EU?

Tags: european-union, taxes, statistics, energy-policy

I can easily find the [total cost](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Electricity_price_statistics) of residential electricity for each country in the EU, but I would like to know/see how much of that is taxes and fixed network tariff. I could find such information [for Germany](https://www.econstor.eu/handle/10419/92970) (which has the highest prices), from some years ago.

[image]

But I'd like to know if the lower cost in the other EU countries is due to lower taxes/tariffs or lower production costs.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to find a graph [for 2015](https://www.isi.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/isi/dokumente/ccx/2016/report_ecofys2016.pdf) (which is a bit dated)

[image]

That year Denmark rather than Germany had the highest prices. So it does seem that the highest prices correspond to the highest levies and taxes. (As also noted in the comments below, this graph only has the non-production costs. Denmark really had the highest prices that year; there's a graph just with the prices at beginning of that paper; fig 1, but with no structure breakdowns.)

I found a simpler but more recent graph in another [EU report](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=COM:2019:1:FIN&from=EN), which being for 2017 has Germany ranked first, but this one also has the production cost in the breakdown.

[image]

This latter paper also has a similar breakdown of industrial electricity. Interestingly, Denmark is far from the top in the latter category.

[image]

If someone knows of a better source/study on this (e.g. a regression) I'd accept that as a better answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd: yes, the total cost is way back in fig 1 in the paper.